# WkHtmlToPdfDotNet conversion in AzureFunction hangs. Running on local environment

Tags: azure-functions

I've got this code that was put in an Azure Function (HTTP Trigger) and works perfectly in the local env. When put it into the Azure Function, it throws a timeout error. I'm running on .NET 7.

```
public class ConvertToPDF
{
    private readonly ILogger<ConvertToPDF> _logger;

    public ConvertToPDF(ILogger<ConvertToPDF> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [Function("ConvertPDF")]
    public async Task<HttpResponseData> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequestData req)
    {
        string requestBody = await req.ReadAsStringAsync();

        _logger.LogInformation($"PDFGenerator called with payload: {requestBody}");

        try
        {
            var requestData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ConvertToPDFRequest>(requestBody);

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(requestData.HTML))
            {
                _logger.LogError("HTML content is not present, nothing to convert");

                var errorResponse = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

                // Create your error object
                var errorObject = new
                {
                    ErrorMessage = "HTML content is not present, nothing to convert"
                };

                await errorResponse.WriteAsJsonAsync(errorObject);

                return errorResponse;
            }

            var fileBytes = GetPDFBytes(requestData.HTML);

            var response = req.CreateResponse();
            response.WriteString("Test4");

            return response;
            //    response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/pdf");

            //    string filename = string.IsNullOrEmpty(requestData.FileName) ? "file.pdf": requestData.FileName ;

            //    response.Headers.Add($"Content-Disposition", $"attachment; filename=\"{filename}\""); // Replace "your_filename.pdf" with the desired filename

            //    await response.Body.WriteAsync(fileBytes);

            //    return response;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError(ex, "PDFGenerator");
        var errorResponse = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

        // Create your error object
        var errorObject = new
            {
                ErrorMessage = ex.Message
            };

        await errorResponse.WriteAsJsonAsync(errorObject);

        return errorResponse;
    }
}

private static byte[] GetPDFBytes(string htmlContent)
{
    WkHtmlToPdfDotNet.BasicConverter c = new BasicConverter(new PdfTools());

    var doc = new HtmlToPdfDocument()
        {
            GlobalSettings =
                  {
                      ColorMode = ColorMode.Color,
                      Orientation = Orientation.Portrait,
                      PaperSize = PaperKind.A4,
                      DPI = 300,
                      Margins =
                          {
                              Top = 20,
                              Right = 0,
                              Left = 0
                          }
                  },
            Objects =
                 {
                     new ObjectSettings()
                         {
                             PagesCount = true,
                             HtmlContent = htmlContent,
                             WebSettings =
                                   {
                                       PrintMediaType = true,
                                       EnableJavascript = true,
                                       DefaultEncoding = "utf-8",
                                       EnableIntelligentShrinking = true
                                   },
                             FooterSettings =
                                   {
                                       FontSize = 14,
                                       FontName = "Lato",
                                       Center = "[page]",
                                       Line = true,
                                       Spacing = 2.812
                                   },
                             LoadSettings =
                                 {
                                     LoadErrorHandling = ContentErrorHandling.Ignore,
                                     StopSlowScript = false
                                 },
                 }
            }
        };

        return c.Convert(doc);
    }
}
```

I think the issue is related to the usage of Stream under the FunctionAzure or the usage of MemoryStream. But I cannot figure out how to solve it.

Any suggestion?